# count VS select in LINQ - which is faster?

Tags: sql, linq, performance, iqueryable

I'm using `IQueryable<T>` interfaces throughout my application and defer execution of SQL on the DB until methods like `.ToList()`

I will need to find the Count of certain lists sometimes -without- needing to use the data in the list being counted. I know from my SQL experience that a SQL COUNT() is far less work for the DB than the equivalent SELECT statement that returns all the rows.

So my question is: will it be less work on the DB to return the count from the `IQueryable<T>`'s `Count()` method than rendering the `IQueryable<T>` to a list and invoking the list's `Count()` method?

I suspect it will given that the `ToList()` will fire the SELECT sql and then in a separate query count the rows. I'm hoping the `Count()` on the `IQueryable<T>` simply renders out the sql for a sql COUNT() query instead. But im not certain. Do you know?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Calling `ToList()` will return a genuine `List<T>` with all the data, which means fetching all the data. Not good.

Calling `Count()` should indeed render the SQL to do the count on the database side. Much better.

The simplest way to check this, however, is to enable logging in your data context (or whatever the equivalent is for your particular provider) and see what queries are actually being sent.

Comment: thanx Jon. i can verify that the IQueryable's Count() method does gen the proper SQL COUNT() rather than the list's Count property that must have the SELECT fired. here is also a kool TextWriter for those who want to watch the logging - http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Kris/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=11

Comment: Sql Server's COUNT will still be slow as it causes a table scan!

Comment: @Slaggg, if you have an index it will only do an index scan on the smallest index you have. If you have no indexes it will still reduce the network load on the database server (compared to returning all rows).

Comment: @Albin - You are correct.  However indexes themselves can still be quite large.  Developers should just be aware that COUNT is not the trivial operation you'd expect it to be.

Comment: @Slaggg: Bear in mind that the OP has already stated: "I know from my SQL experience that a SQL COUNT() is far less work for the DB than the equivalent SELECT statement that returns all the rows." While it may not be trivial, I think claiming that it *will* cause a table scan is misleading.

Comment: @Jon - You are correct, I should not have said table scan. That said, the question is about efficiency. And for efficiency in database apps, a prime concern is minimizing IO. Developers should realize that to understand the cost of a COUNT, find the size of your smallest index (or the table if no indexes), and all that data has to be read from disk (if not yet cached), while the table is locked. I think many assume COUNT is trivial like it is for many framework data structures, a simple O(1) memory lookup. But it's not. That's my point.

Comment: @Slaggg But even if the table has no indexes a scan for COUNT is less work that a scan that even selects one column correct?

Comment: @cottsak Are you referring to my sysindexes approach below?  That's a index seek, not table scan (sysindexes is indexed on the id column).  For small tables this doesn't matter much.  But if your tables are large, the IO of seeking on sysindexes is far less than the IO of an index scan or table scan.

Comment: No. I mean a scan - in the case where I want the exact count (with locks).

Comment: @cottsak - in that case, yes, count is cheaper b/c of the smaller returned data size.  Just be aware of the IO going on.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it's a hard and fast rule, but linq method you add to an Iqueryable will be added into the linq expression tree - unless they are one of the methods that actually cause the tree to be evaluated (like ToList and Single etc).
In the case of LinqToSql you'll know if it can't convert something into the SQL statement because you'll get a runtime exception stating that the method is not supported.

eg

```
var something = dbContext.SomeTable
  .Select(c => c.col1 == "foo")
  .Distinct()
  .ToList()
  .Count()
```

In the above, Select() and Distinct() are included in the sql query passed to the server because they are added to an Iqueryable. Count() is just acting on the list that was returned by the sql query. So you don't want to do it that way :-)

In your case, Count() will definitely be faster that Select() because the resulting sql statement will indeed incorporate the count so the server only needs to return a single number rather than a list of rows.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using SQL Server, Count() is still very expensive because it causes a table scan (or index scan, see comments on primary answer).  And, by default Linq doesn't use the read uncomitted isolation level, which makes things worse due to locking.

If you can live with the result being a dirty result and an approximation of the total number of rows, the following code will be considerably faster than using Count().  In my experience, the value returned by this code is rarely different than the true count of rows.

```
/// <summary>A very fast method for counting rows in a table.</summary>
public static long FastRowCount(DataContext context, string tableName)
{
    const string template = "SELECT rowcnt FROM sys.sysindexes WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('{0}') AND indid < 2";
    string query = string.Format(template, tableName);
    return context.ExecuteQuery<long>(query).Single();
}
```

Comment: It's a fair assumption that anything that anyone is COUNTing on in a production environment is going to be indexed.